# How can i overwrite (instead of append) the data in destination table in Airflow "DataflowTemplateOperator()"?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, airflow

I am using Airflow DataflowTemplateOperator() for migrating data from Mssql to Bigquery using JDBC to Bigquery dataflow template.

By default it appends data into destination Bigquery table.

I want to truncate the table first and then write new rows.

Is there any default parameter to change the dataflow / DataflowTemplateOperator settings from append to overwrite ???

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow templates are publicly available in GitHub, including the [Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery). Although, you can not directly modify them, you can create a custom template by using the provided one as the source code, only changing the `WriteDisposition`.

If you check [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java#L102) the source code for the template you are currently using, you can see that on the 102nd line the `WriteDisposition` is [WRITE_APPEND](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.html#WRITE_APPEND)` instead of [WRITE_TRUNCATE](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.html#WRITE_TRUNCATE). Below, I will describe the steps to change the template by creating a new one.

1. In order to create a new template, copy the source code from the Google's GitHub page, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java), to a new `.java` file;
2. In the line number 102, change the `WriteDisposition` to [WRITE_TRUNCATE](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.html#WRITE_TRUNCATE);
3. After editing the code, you need to create and stage your template, such as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates);
4. Make sure that the destination table exists in BigQuery and [these](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery) ***requirements for the template*** are met.
5. Execute the custom template, such as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#custom-templates)

Comment: @JosephN,  if you found this information useful. Please, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.